# How can i reorder(Drag & drop) Listview items in Windows 8 metro app

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, windows-8

How can i reorder(Drag & drop to arrange item positions)  List view items in Windows 8 metro app(HTML 5/JavaScript), I have a listview and the items are binded from the SQLite database, please share some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView in WinJS doesn't support drag& drop. It's highly unlikely you'll be able to shoe horn it on top.

I'd suggest building an alternative UI. If your data is small enough (eg under a few hundred items) you could just use standard layouts,rather than a listView, and use HTML drag and drop techniques from around the web.